# conditional format based on external cell value

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

would like to format a row based on the value of one cell.  i.e., I would like to turn a row 6 green if Q6 is "yes"
have tried many variations of

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),17))>0
```

and

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),17))="yes"
```

Comment: `=$Q6="Yes"` and make sure you apply it starting in row 6.

Comment: This works for row 6. I tried to extend it to other rows (7-30) and it didn't work. I assume I could do it manually for each row, but the number of rows is prohibitive.

Comment: Are you wanting row 7 to turn green if Q6 is "yes", or if Q7 is "yes"?

Comment: No.  I want row 7 to turn green if Q7 is yes. That's why I was trying to apply the row() function

Comment: Then apply the rule `=$Q6="Yes"` to rows 6-30.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a rule with the formula `=$Q6="Yes"` and apply it to all the rows in question, starting with row 6.

[image]